# HTML CSS List-Style Compatibility

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm working on front-end of an intranet website.

The problem I have is with to do with the list compatibility. What I want to do is to style the list items, for example, instead of having bullets, I would like to have arrows. I have inserted the arrows, but it displays differently on Firefox compared with Chrome.

On Firefox it displays the bullet point on the corner, but on Chrome it displays inline with the link text which is what I'm looking for.

Here is the CSS for the list and arrow:

```
.jt-menu .item-280 li li {
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 16px;
     margin: 1px 0 0 1px;
     text-align: left;
     width: 172px;
     list-style: disc inside url("../../../../images/barrow.png");   
}
```

Comment: please recreate your problem in http://jsfiddle.net, so we can view it online. just posting CSS alone doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Samuel. I have created the menu on jsfiddle.net, On the css the line that you can look at is line 162. here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/beseti/tatj2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.jt-menu > li > ul ul li {
    width: 240px !important;
}
.jt-menu > li > ul ul a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more left-margin and setting `line-height` as tall as your image.